# UIPagecontrol with Images

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, pagecontrol

I'm trying to use the page control feature along with UIScrollView to display a set of images on my IOS app, i've seen some tutorials but they all show how to change colors, how can i have some images loaded and use page control to go through them?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page;
{
    UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*page, 200, scrollView.frame.size.width, 100)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[viewControllers objectAtIndex:page]];

    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

`viewControllers` stores the name of the image that you have taken.

Comment: Nice, but how do i add the images names...sorry i'm kind of new to all this

Comment: soon ill post a tutorial on that in a couple of days then ill provide u the link for the Tutorial.

Comment: [http://abhilashreddykallepu.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/scrolling-images-on-a-scrollview/]

Comment: O l et me know please as soon as it's up ok?

Answer (score 0):

Using PageControl, you can navigate through views, so you can put imageviews on the view and set the images on imageviews.

Comment: but how do you navigate between views the example i've seen they just use background colors